# htacceess to web.config for wordpress & codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-config, plesk

I have codeigniter on root folder. And wordpress on sub-folder (home). Following was the htaccess:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore * 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
RewriteRule ^$ home [L]
```

I've made **web.config** that removes **index.php** for codeigniter & redirects to wordpress (home folder) when root domain is visited. But in the following **web.config** I get 3 issues:

1. wordpress permalinks doesn't work.
2. codeigniter only works if urls used with **index.php**.
3. safari always shows `403 Forbidden. Access denied`.

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true" >
                        <match url="^$" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="/home" />
                    </rule>
                
                    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

PS: Site is hosted on windows plesk (obsidian)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true"  patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                        <match url="*" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                             <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="/home/*" negate="true" />  
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
        
  <location path="home">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <remove name="home" />
          <rule name="home" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
            <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="home/index.php" redirectType="Found"/>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    </configuration>
```